# How to extrude an extrusion using VTK python ..how to convert the first extrusion to something useable in vtkLinearExtrusionFilter()?

Tags: python, vtk, modeling, paraview

Funny question, and I am really new to this (please dont assume i know anything lol)

But I have taken a set of points and converted to a polyline (polydata) and then extruded this polydata using vtkLinearExtrusionFilter into a surface.

Now I would like to extrude that surface into a 3d solid, how can I extrude the 1st extrusion? How to properly save 1st extrusion as vtkDataObject (see error below)

**TypeError:**

> SetInputData argument 1: method requires a vtkDataObject, a
>   vtkLinearExtrusionFilter was provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take the output of the filter, and not the filter itself. This output is a vtk data object.

```
first_extrusion = vtkLinearExtrusionFilter()
# set parameters ....
first_extrusion.Update()

second_extrusion = vtkLinearExtrusionFilter()
second_extrusion.SetInputData( first_extrusion.GetOutput() )
# set other parameters ...
```